# Symfony: Custom Twig Rendering for Entity Type

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have an issue with rendering an **Entity Type** in a **Symfony Form**.

Here is what I call in the form **type**:

```
$builder
            ->add('categories', EntityType::class, array
            (
                'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\ArticleCategory',
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => true,
                'constraints' => array
                (
                    new NotBlank(array('message' => 'Select Category'))
                )
            ))
```

This is the template I am trying to do:

```
{% form_theme form _self %}
{% block _article_categories_entry_row %}
    <div class="ckbox ckbox-default">
       {{ form_widget(form) }}
       {{ form_label(form) }}
       {{ form_errors(form) }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

In the same template I am doing

```
 {{ form_start(form) }}
 {{ form_row(form.categories) }}
 {{ form_end(form) }}
```

The weird thing happens when I use **block _article_categories_entry_widget** and it picks it up however it renders the label twice. Any ideas how to manage to situation ? In this scenario above it doesn't render or adds the ckbox class at all ! :(

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through your `form.categories` in template as below and render checkboxes as you want.

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{% for category in form.categories %}
    {{ form_label(category) }}
    {{ form_widget(category) }}
{% endfor %}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you named your custom block `_article_categories_entry_row`, I assume, your form is named `ArticleType`.

The custom block for a specific form field should be named with following pattern:

```
_<form_name>_<field_name>_<part_name>
```

Possible parts as `row`, `errors`, `widget`, `label`. You're using `row` here.

But the `entry` part of block name is unnecessary.

Try with:

```
{% block _article_categories_row %}
```

You can find more details in [Symfony Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html#how-to-customize-an-individual-field)